# iOS Swift, with one common method in protocol and two implementations in two ViewControllers, how to decide which ViewControllers method is invoked?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a protocol

```
protocol HandleEmbedController: class {
    func printMsg()
}
```

and 2 container views and 2 corresponding ViewControllers

```
class EnemyBaseVC: UIViewController, HandleEmbedController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    var value1 = ""

    func printMsg(){
        print("printing some embedded message")
    }

}
```

and

```
class EnemyBase2VC: UIViewController, HandleEmbedController {

    func printMsg() {
        print("enemy base 2 message")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

and both use the protocol `HandleEmbedController` and implement `printMsg` function.

In the main ViewController I have

```
class HomeBaseVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    var handleEmbedController:HandleEmbedController?

    @IBAction func onclick(_ sender: UIButton) {

        handleEmbedController?.printMsg()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "embedseg"){
            if let embed = segue.destination as? EnemyBaseVC     {
                self.handleEmbedController = embed
            }
        }

        if (segue.identifier == "embedseg2"){
            if let embed = segue.destination as? EnemyBase2VC     {
                self.handleEmbedController = embed
            }
        }


    }
}
```

When button is clicked always `EnemyBaseVC` method is invoked and prints

```
printing some embedded message
```

Is there any way to decide which method is to be invoked?

**UPDATE** 
[image: Main storyboard layout]

Comment: The problem is not to decide which method will be invoked. The method invoked will be the `printMsg` implemented in whatever class is `handleEmbedController` pointing to. The error is not in `onclick` func
I believe it's in the `if let embed = segue.destination as? EnemyBase2VC` or `if (segue.identifier == "embedseg2")`

Comment: I mean, the code in those two conditions seems to be correct. What I meant to say is that those `if`s are where your logic might break. But the error probably comes from the segue in the storyboard.
Can be a typo in the identifier or the class of the destination.

Comment: @Gonzo Good catch!

Comment: @Gonzo I checked the identifiers. They are correct. When application starts viewDidLoad() in EnemyBaseVC only invoked. EnemyBaseVC2 is not invoked.  Is there a way that i can invoke them programmatically on a button click

Comment: Can you share your storyboard layout? If both the embed segues are triggered on load, then whichever happens second will be the handleEmbedController.

It sounds like the second one is never triggered though, based on your comments. How are you triggering the "embedseg2" segue?

Comment: @BJHStudios Updated the question with layout. I think "embedseg2" is not triggered. I dont know why. Is there a way to trigger this

Comment: @BJHStudios Yes its not triggered. I cant figure out why either. I removed segueId checks and tried. Still it wont create the segue.destination for embedseg2

Comment: @IsankaLakshan based on what I see, both should be being triggered when your main view controller is loaded. I would put a breakpoint in EnemyBaseVC viewDidLoad and make sure it's not getting instantiated twice. Otherwise if you want to take this to chat and share your code, I'm happy to take a look and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two container views, both segues will be triggered on load, and handleEmbedController will reference the one ViewController that is loaded last.

If you have some logic to decide which one should be referenced, then you can use it to decide which ViewController will be referenced, like so:

```
class HomeBaseVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

var handleEmbedController:HandleEmbedController?

//  comes from your decision logic
var decisionMaker: Bool = false

@IBAction func onclick(_ sender: UIButton) {

    handleEmbedController?.printMsg()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "embedseg"),
        let embed = segue.destination as? EnemyBaseVC,
        decisionMaker {
        self.handleEmbedController = embed
    }

    else if (segue.identifier == "embedseg2"),
        let embed = segue.destination as? EnemyBase2VC,
        !decisionMaker {
        self.handleEmbedController = embed
    }
  }
}
```

be aware that this will set the handleEmbedController on load, if you need more complex behavior, you might as well handle the assignment of handleEmbedController elsewhere than in the segue.

Since this is a scenario where your base ViewController must communicate with more than one object, you can also use notifications instead of delegations. This way, you can decide which message to send when user taps the button. Your base ViewController would look something like this

```
class HomeBaseVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    //  comes from your decision logic
    var decisionMaker: Bool = true

    @IBAction func onclick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "BUTTON_WAS_TAPPED"), object: nil, userInfo: ["decision" : decisionMaker])
    }
}
```

while the enemy ViewControllers would look like this (the second one would be the same except the decision value to handle)

```
class EnemyBaseVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "BUTTON_WAS_TAPPED"),
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: nil) { notification in
                                                if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
                                                    let decision = userInfo["decision"] as? Bool,
                                                    decision {
                                                        self.printMsg()
                                                }
        }
    }

    var value1 = ""

    private func printMsg(){
        print("printing some embedded message")
    }
}
```

Comment: prepare method is called only once right? If both container views are in main story board, handleEmbedController only has the instance of which ever the embedseg initialized last. Is there any way that we can set embed = segue.destination as? EnemyBase2VC in button click

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But again when there are 2 child controller classes viewDidLoad() is not called in the second class.